# How to use the fold method for a future type?

Tags: flutter, future, dartz

I have this method as my repository:

```
Future<Either<Exceptions, bool>> userRegister(FormData formData) async {
    try {
      final response = await _mourdakApi.userRegister(formData);
      bool _isSuccesed;
      if (response.statusCode == 200)
        _isSuccesed = true;
      else
        _isSuccesed = false;
      return Right(_isSuccesed);
    } catch (e) {
      return Left(
        Exceptions(
          message: e.toString(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Now I want to use fold method here:

```
final failedOrResult = _mourdakRepository.userRegister(event.formData);

return failedOrResult.fold(
      (exception) => UserExceptionState(exception.message),
      (isSuccesed) => UserRegisterState(isSuccesed));
```

But I got this error:

```
The method 'fold' isn't defined for the type 'Future'
```

Comment: Consider adding [repro]. Also check [ask] to improve this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it hasn't already solved, but only the await is missing.
Another way would be to use the Task method, defined in lib dartz

```
final failedOrResult = await _mourdakRepository.userRegister(event.formData);

return failedOrResult.fold(
      (exception) => UserExceptionState(exception.message),
      (isSuccesed) => UserRegisterState(isSuccesed));
```